# How to create loop for in and put result to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm really beginner with for in loop. I would like to create some loop that will be

```
df['sentiment_rat2'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda polarity: 'positiv' if polarity >= 0.3 else 'negative')
```

And I got the error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Sentiment' and
> 'float'

And this is my dataframe:

```
Text    Tweet_tokenized Tweet_nonstop   Tweet_stemmed   sentiment   sentiment_rat2
0   0   RT @bennyjohnson:  BOMBSHELL \n\nVeteran &am... [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshell, veteran, amp, bu...   [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshell, veteran, amp, bu...   [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshel, veteran, amp, bus...   (0.0, 0.07142857142857142)
```

I put my screen. My printscreen isn't work sorry
https://ibb.co/hDd0PNy

Comment: Your code looks fine, it seems you're trying to compare Sentiment class with float, Sentiment must be a wrapper object that contains the numerical field you want to compare. If it's coming from a library check its documentation to retrieve the numerical value. For e.g. if it is a state variable called polarity then you would have

`df['sentiment_rat2'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda sentiment: 'positiv' if sentiment.polarity >= 0.3 else 'negative')
`

Comment: great thannk ! and if i would like add some for example "neutrals" it will be "and if sentiment.polarity <0.3 > 0 esle : or try use range ?

Comment: I would write a function that handles these cases and then pass that function to df.apply(), I don't like my lambdas to be too messy, but if you must something like `'positive' if sentiment > 0 else ('negative' if sentiment < 0 else 'neutral')`

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding, you want a new column in the dataframe that takes 1 of 2 string values, either "positiv" or "negative", depending on the sentiment score? If that is what you are going for, you could try:

```
df['sentiment_rat2'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: np.where(x >= 0.3, "positiv", "negative"))
```

I'm not too sure where the variable polarity is coming from and the snippet of your dataframe is not very clear. Maybe a screenshot would help to clear things up if I have misunderstood anything about your question :)

Comment: Hey i will put link to screen for my DF . Thanks